# Merge 2 CSV files with mapped values in another file separated by comma

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

here is my problem:

I have tow csv files as follows:

**Book1.csv**

```
Id  Product
0   aaaa
1   bbbb
2   cccc
3   dddd
```

**Book2.csv**

```
Id  Attribute
0   aaad
0   sssd
1   fffd
1   gggd
1   cccd
2   bbbd
3   hhhd
3   bbbd
```

I want merge above files and get an output file as this:

```
Product Attributes
aaaa    aaad, sssd
bbbb    fffd, gggd, cccd
cccc    bbbd
dddd    hhhd, bbbd
```

The code I am using right now is:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("Book2.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=0)
merged = a.merge(b, how='left', left_on='Id', right_on='Id' )
merged.rename(columns={
                 'Product': 'Product',
                 'Attribute': 'Attributes'}, inplace=True)
merged = merged[['Product','Attributes']]
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

what I get from this is :

```
Product Attributes
aaaa    aaad
aaaa    sssd
bbbb    fffd
bbbb    gggd
bbbb    cccd
cccc    bbbd
dddd    hhhd
dddd    bbbd
```

All the Attributes and Products are merged correctly. But what I want is merge Attibutes into one string and separate by comma (not line by line). How do I do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way.

```
g = df2.groupby('Id')['Attribute'].apply(', '.join)
df1['Attributes'] = df1['Id'].map(g)
```

**Result**

```
   Id Product          Attributes
0   0    aaaa          aaad, sssd
1   1    bbbb    fffd, gggd, cccd
2   2    cccc                bbbd
3   3    dddd          hhhd, bbbd
```

If you want to just combine to `list`, you can use this instead, though it won't print nicely:

```
g = df2.groupby('Id')['Attribute'].apply(list)
```

**Explanation**

- Group `df2` Attributes by Id and aggregate to list.
- Map to column in `df1` via `pd.Series.map`.

Comment: it's great. 

Thank you so much  for your response. :)